# viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: Not being called automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, screen-orientation

I want to call the iOS 8 method `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` to handle transitioning to different device orientations but it does not seem to be called automatically. I have previously handled orientation changes via `NSNotifications` (i.e. `orientationChanged:`).

I have included `NSLogs` within the `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` method but they are never called and the following code didn't help either:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Anyone else experience any similar issues with this method?

Comment: It _is_ called automatically. Can you give more details on why you think it is not?

Comment: It should be called, you must have a bug. BTW. why won't you use `AutoLayout` if you're using `Storyboards` or `layoutSubviews` if you're implementing views in code..? This way your implementation is in one place and it is less likely to broke on new iOS versions.

Comment: My logging here proves that it is called: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p258launchIntoRotationEvents/bk2ch06p258launchIntoRotationEvents/ViewController.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had a navigation controller that had the following method:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Changing to `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll` fixed the issue.